# Can't get instant of WifiManager

Tags: java, android

Why can't I get an instance of wifi manager? It gives me the error:

> Suspicious cast to WifiManager for a WIFI_SERVICE: expected WifiManager.

I'm just trying to get the local ip eg : 192.168.1.10 ..etc

```
 compileSdkVersion 28
 minSdkVersion 18
 targetSdkVersion 28
```

thank you

```
final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                final WifiInfo connectionInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
```

Comment: Put your error log if you still did not find the solution

Comment: i found it ,there where two classes named WifiManager